# Is "connexion" synonymous with "connection"?

Tags: synonyms

Is *connexion* synonymous with *connection*?
Can I use it, for example, in *an ethernet connexion*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[No, at least not in American English.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connexion)

From Wikipedia:

> Connexion is the original and variant
>   spelling of "connection", common until
>   at least the 19th century, and still
>   occasionally used in British English
>   (it was the house style of The Times
>   of London as recently as the 1980s).
>   It is derived from the Latin connexio,
>   hence the spelling, unlike most words
>   ending in "-ction" which are derived
>   from Latin words ending in "-ctio"
>   (e.g. "protection" from protectio).

I've never seen that spelling in use in the US.

Comment: Sounds like the name of some Technology company to me. (American English speaker). Never seen it written like that, but would associate it with an alternative spelling of Connection if seen in older texts.

Comment: @Aequitarum Custos You're not the only one that thought this would made a good tech company name:  http://www.connexiontechnologies.net/cnxntech/index

Comment: Hah, figures

Comment: Could also be a typo from someone who speaks French or another language in which it's always written connexion. I know it's a mistake I often make.

Answer (score 6):

In British English, *connexion* is an alternative spelling of *connection*; American English only uses *connection*.

The origin of the word connection explains the reason of this.
*Connection* has origin from the Latin *connexio(n-)*; only in the 18th century the spelling *-ct-* started to be used, on the pattern of words like *collect*, and *collection*.

Comment: On a side note, the formation *connectio* would be impossible in classical Latin: *connexion* is hence etymologically preferable, if we maintain that words should not be based on folk etymology where possible. At any rate, there was as far as I know no verb *connecto* in classical Latin, only *necto* existed; it was probably a medieval or Renaissance invention. This is logical if you consider what the *con-* has to add to the meaning of *necto*: nothing. The word with the intended meaning that actually existed in classical Latin was *nexus* — and even that was, I believe, a late word.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely used in British English. I came across this variant of spelling in *Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring*. If we look closely at the author of the book, J.R.R Tolkien, he is a Briton and wrote this book in 1954. The usage of this spelling is dated and it's closer related to 19th century/ early 20th century. In Canada, we spell it just like in the US: *connection*.

Answer (score 1):

It mainly appears in (some) British texts and/or archaic texts. In use of typical American English, the word "connexion" would simply be replaced with the standard term, connection.

The term "connexion" is depreciated in modern American English. It is still (sometimes) used in British English.

---

**An Example of Encountering the Term Connexion In a Modern Context**

I found the use of the term "connexion" in some translations of Kant's *Prolegomena to any Future Metaphysics*.

Kant is still being read in philosophy today, so that is one use of the term "connexion" in a modern context.

This was the book:--

(https://www.amazon.de/Kants-Prolegomena-Future-Metaphysics-English-ebook/dp/B01LZ8UD4C)

You can find the Kant quote below.

---

**Research**:--

*Sources and References*:--

- (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/connexion)
- (http://grammarist.com/spelling/connexion/)

*Other References and Further Reading*:--

- (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/connexion)

*MLA Citation*:--

> > > "I therefore first tried whether Hume's objection could not be put into a general  form, and soon found that the concept of the *connexion* of cause and effect was  by no means the only idea by which the understanding thinks the connexion of  things a priori, but rather that metaphysics consists altogether of such *connexions*."
> >
> > *Emphasis via italics is by me and is not from the original text.*
>
> -- Kant, Immanuel. “Kant's Prolegomena: To Any Future Metaphysics (English Edition) Kindle Edition.” Kant's Prolegomena: To Any Future Metaphysics (English Edition) EBook: Immanuel Kant: Amazon.de: Kindle-Shop, [https://www.amazon.com/Kants-Prolegomena-Future-Metaphysics-English-ebook/dp/B01LZ8UD4C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LZ8UD4C).