# Why are "connection" and "connexion" both used in the same work?

Tags: differences, nouns, synonyms, orthography, history

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13909/is-connexion-synonymous-with-connection), [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=connexion,connection&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connexion), and several dictionaries all say that *connexion* is an alternate, obsolete spelling of *connection*.

I am reading a several-hundred page treatise (Milton S. Terry, 1890, *Biblical Hermeneutics*), wherein the author uses both forms, favoring *connexion* considerably. The instances of *connexion* (84) are listed [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=UQ8_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA17&dq=biblical%20hermeneutics%20inauthor:terry&hl=en&ei=C2-4Toy7MMHhiAK_2cmIBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=connexion&f=false), and the instances of *connection* (9) are listed [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=UQ8_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA17&dq=biblical%20hermeneutics%20inauthor:terry&hl=en&ei=C2-4Toy7MMHhiAK_2cmIBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=connection&f=false). I think what I am reading is the author's 500-page condensation of the work linked.

My question is this: Why is *connection* used at all?

Does it really mean something different? It appears to be used synonymously. Is it merely an instance of non-standardized spelling (as with the diaries of Lewis and Clark, where a word can spelt multiple ways in a very short space)? This would be the only instance of this that I have found so far. Is there a different explanation that I haven't yet considered?

Comment: can spelt: you mean "can be spelled"? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come across many instances of *connexion* in various readings, and based on my experience, I have to say that I have never seen a usage of *connexion* which would not felicitously be replaced with *connection*.  The Wikipedia page and EL&U question you linked bear this out.

All that in mind, I would say that the variant spellings are almost certainly evidence of non-standardization.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really want to know, here's the OED's explanation:

> Etymology:  < Latin *connexiōn-em* (in classical Latin *cōnexiōn-* )
>   binding together, close union, n. of action < *co(n)nect-ĕre*
>   (participial stem *co(n)nex-* ) to connect v.: compare French *connexion*
>   (14th cent. Oresme), Provençal *connexio* , Spanish *conexion* ,
>   Portuguese *connexão* , Italian *connessione* . The etymological spelling
>   *connexion* is the original in English; in 17th cent. it was supported
>   by the verb *connex v*.; after the latter was displaced by *connect v.*,
>   the n. began c1725–50 to be often spelt *connection* , a spelling which,
>   under the influence of etymologically-formed words, such as *affection*
>   , *collection , direction , inspection* (all < Latin participial stems
>   in *-ect-* ), is now very frequent.
>
> The earlier English lexicographers, including Bailey, Johnson, Walker,
>   Todd, Crabb, recognize *connexion* only. *Connection* appears in Webster
>   (1828) who says ‘For the sake of regular analogy, I have inserted
>   *Connection* as the derivative of the English *connect* , and would
>   discard *connexion* ’. This preference has been followed by other
>   dictionaries in U.S. Latham would differentiate the two spellings and
>   use *connexion* only in senses 5– 8 *Connexion* is the official and
>   invariable spelling in sense 8, and was used in all senses by the
>   majority of writers (or printers) in England until the mid-20th cent.,
>   when *connection* became more usual.